# Wrap image to other side of canvas

Tags: gimp, layers, canvas

I'm working on a project where I'd like to be able to move an layer on a canvas, but have that layer wrap around to the other side if it goes off the edge of the canvas.

So if I had this originally:

[image]

Then moved the circle to the right, it would end up like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way for me to do this in gimp, or will I have to split it and rearrange it manually?

Comment: I believe Gimp has some sort of Offset feature much like Photoshop. I've never really used Gimp so I can't really say how that would work, but... In Photoshop, to get what you want, you could use the Offset filter and give it X offset: `document width divided by two`.

Comment: @Joonas - GIMP has about 90% of everything Photoshop has  - it's just a matter of a different interface with functions and filters located in different menus, or with different names.  After all, I'm sure Adobe would sue if GIMP were exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `Layer>Transform>Offset...`.

But a simpler method could be to create a layer which is 3x3 the size of the canvas, and tile your layer on it. The canvas will act as a viewport on it. The thing to keep in mind is that selections are always clipped by the canvas, so `Select>All` only selects the visible part. But with `Select>None` all the layer is affected.

In Gimp 2.10 you can use the new "Symmetry painting" in "tiled" mode to paint the extra bits exactly like the visible part.